# Обработка пользовательских событий

Tags: php, html

У меня есть картинки, которые я перемещаю в отдельные div-ы, специально для каждого типа картинок. Как можно фиксировать тот момент, когда все картинки перемещены в свои div-ы, и показать картинки одного div-а в slideshow?

Comment: Каким образом перемещаете?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю Вам поможет эта статья http://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop

Comment: спасибо но посмотрел эту статью, это не тот